# A different expression for expected value of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $E[X]<\infty$. I need to show that:

$E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>t) \ dt$ (Riemann integral)

where $E[X]=\int_\Omega X \ dP =\int_\mathbb{R}x \  dP_X$   (Lebesgue integral).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X]&=\int_\Omega X\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\
&=\int_\Omega \int_0^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{[0,X]}(t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\
&\underset{\text{Fubini}}{=}\int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \boldsymbol 1_{[0,X]}(t)\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P\{X>t\}\,\mathrm d t.
\end{align}

You can make more general by proving that if $\varphi \in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$, s.t. $\varphi \geq 0$ and $\varphi (0)=0$, then $$\mathbb E[\varphi (X)]=\int_0^\infty \varphi '(t)\mathbb P\{X>t\}\,\mathrm d t.$$

Comment: Thanks. I can also see taht the generalization to $\varphi$ is straightforward.